# C++ Polymorphism and specific methods

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism

Given 3 classes.

```
class vehicle{
public: 
void start();
}

class airplane: public vehicle{
void start();
void setRoute(route r);
void setAltitude(altitude a);
}

class boat: public vehicle{
void start();
void setRoute(route r);
}
```

Suppose we receive a parameter by command line that let us understand if we will manage an airplane or a boat.

```
Vehicle* v;


if (parameter == 1) {
   v = new airplane();
   v->setRoute(r);
   v->setALtitude(a);
}

if (parameter != 1) {
   v = new boat();
   v->setRoute(r);
}


v->start();
```

Note that different methods are called for boat and airplane before start.
(Start is the only common method)
This code will not work because v doesn't contains methods setRoute/SetALtitude.

What's the correct way of implement this pattern?

Comment: Sorry, write `if (parameter==1)` instead of `if (parameter=1)`...

Comment: In this instance I would be tempted to make altitude part of the `route`. Otherwise if they have distinct abilities then you can give them distinct interfaces like `class flyable` and `class sailable` so a plain could be `class airplane: public vehicle, public flyable {}` and a boat `class boat: public vehicle, public sailable {}`...

Comment: but distinct interfaces doesn't allows me to use polymorphism, right?

Comment: @Franconet Its not polymorphism when you try to control different interfaces from a common base (which is what you are trying to do here). Polymorphism is when multiple types share the same interface so you don't need to know the exact type to control them. So I would argue that having a common interface for each subvariety of vehicle is better polymorphism than trying to fudge a bunch of different acting types under a common all-encompasing interface.

Comment: If the subtypes are too different from one another then I would question if polymorphism is the best solution.

Comment: With polymorphism you can only control different subtypes to the extent they have things in common. Beyond that you have to know the more specific type.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do:

```
if(parameter != 1)
{
    boat *b = new boat;
    b->setRoute(r);
    v = b;
}
```

and similar for `airplane`.

Comment: What if I have this scenario?

`if(parameter != 1)
{
    boat *b = new boat;
    b->setRoute(r);
    v = b;
}


v.start();

/*Now I need to set something else*/


if(parameter != 1)
{
    boat *c = new boat;
    b->SetSomethingElse(r);
    v = b;  // route assignation is lost!
}`

Comment: @Franconet `boat *b = (boat*)v;`? (Or `boat *b = static_cast<boat*>(v);` if you prefer that style of cast)

Answer (score 0):

```
class __declspec(novtable) vehicle{
public: 
    virtual void start();
    virtual void setRoute(route r) = 0;
    virtual void setAltitude(altitude a) = 0;
};

class airplane: public vehicle{
    virtual void start();
    virtual void setRoute(route r);
    virtual void setAltitude(altitude a);
};

class boat: public vehicle{
    virtual void start();
    virtual void setRoute(route r);
    virtual void setAltitude(altitude a);
};
```

Comment: Is `__declspec(novtable)` portable or specific for MSCV ?

Comment: specific for MSCV, but use it optional

Comment: but this can be empty metod

Comment: Sure but in my opinion is not a clear way of programming. What if I have 100 subclasses with 10 specific methods each and only 5-6 common method?